# Is there any way to convert a nestjs module in to npm package?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, nestjs, npm-install

I have nestjs module and it suppose to perform crud operations to a postgres db based on some conditions. In my project this module is being shared among other microservice projects(nestjs) too. To prevent code duplication i want to convert this module in to npm package and install via **npm i** command. When I use this via npm package, import and inject classes from that npm module, it says that particular classes should be within current module context. I added this class to the current module's import section too. But it doesn't work. Anyone have solution for this ?

Comment: like any other nodejs applicaton, you can manage to publish it as a npm package. https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/libraries

Comment: @MicaelLevi Unfortunately, this doesn't cover the part where the library is packed and published to npm.

Comment: that's because there's a bunch of articles on that topic, I guess. Just search on how to publish typescript libs to NPM